# How to get git commit sha of a package install via pip?

Tags: python-3.x, git, pip, virtualenv, setuptools

My team and I are using python 3.7.5 and a virtual environments. We are developing and using a fairly informal package. Its an engineering tool and due to the informal and fast pace we arent using a 0.0.0 versioning scheme yet. Hopwever, I would like an easy way to know exactly which version of the tool people are using if they run into issues. And I need a solution that doesn't require manually updating a version number in setuptools because I don't trust my coworkers to do that.

We are using python setuptools and pip to generate wheel files and install the packages into our virtual environments.

My question is: How can I get the commit sha of a particular package that is installed in the virtual environment at run time?

If the solution involves adding some code to embedd that data via setuptools during installation, thats good too.

Comment: You can't since Python packages are unaware of the VCS your project uses. [`setuptools-scm`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) bakes git commit hash into the version, though.

Comment: getting the commit hash seems like the easy part. running "git describe" or "git describe --always" is a failry easy way to get the hash. The problem I am having, is how best to embed that information into the package.